# How it is possible to get rid of spurious artifacts of Shadow Mapping?

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader, shadow

Spurious artifacts in case of creation of shadows through shadow mapping.[image: hahaha]

I can't understand why many shadows are drawn, and from where they originate?
example: [example](https://preview.c9.io/toly19/webgl_project/en.html)

Comment: How many light sources do you have?

Comment: on a scene 1 light source

Comment: Any super reflective surfaces?

Comment: no, reflections don't influence on shadows.
this program is made by an example with webglacademy.com 
course № 28

Comment: Sorry, I'm just throwing ideas out since no one else is; idk opengl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your shadow map is covering only a fraction of the scene, and is being tiled (repeated) to cover the rest. Change the wrapping mode for the shadow map to `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER`:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
```

And set your border color to `1.0f` or `0.0f`, depending on whether you want things outside the shadow map to be lit or unlit:

```
GLfloat borderColor[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);
```

Comment: webgl of it doesn't support. GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER doesn't support

Comment: @АнатолийГрабаров `ctx.CLAMP_TO_EDGE`

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean shadow acne. when you are rendering a litten surface, you calculate the surface point's distance from the light, and compare it with the distance read from the shadow map. Now ideally these should be equal if the surface is lit, but due to float precision errors there may be slight inaccuracies resulting in shadows where there shouldnt be any.

Solution is to apply an offset, so add a small number like 0.001 to the distance you read from the shadow map. The actual offset should be dependant on the world's scale.

Comment: in my example, bias=0.0022

Comment: This is not [shadow acne](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/elementLinks/08fig03.jpg), this problem is a repeating depth map in combination with a *wrong* shadow projection matrix covering only a subarea of the scene

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the farplane of the shadow camera is high enough!